# joint density from marginals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are possibly dependent random variables, and that we know the density functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ respectively. Can I guarantee that the joint pdf exists? If so can I also show that the cdf of $X$ and $Y$, $P(X+Y\le z)$ exists?

Comment: 1. The cdf always exists, what exactly you need to show? 2. Without the independence assumption, it is hard to find non-trivial sufficient conditions for the joint density to exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the representation of joint distributions through marginals distributions and a copula function (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory) and Sklar's theorem). Whether the joint pdf exists will depend on the properties of the copula function that describes the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. One can easily find a copula such that the joint pdf will exist and also easily find a copula that will give a completely opposite result.